# Как правильно производить Check-In в TFS, когда в проекте используются NuGet-пакеты?

Tags: tfs

При разработке с использованием TFS и NuGet столкнулся с проблемой: если производить check-in всех файлов подряд, при скачивании проекта на других машинах, ссылки на сборки из NuGet становятся недоступными. Как этого избежать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-умолчанию, без дополнительных настроек, заливать необходимо в репозиторий только файлы `packages.config`. Папку `packages` полностью игнорировать([NuGet Package Restore](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore)). Тогда ссылки на сборки из NuGet будут рабочими и файлы успешно будут восстанавливаться на других машинах.

Попробуйте почистить папку `packages` полностью, и попробовать выполнить сборку проекта. 
Файлы библиотек перед сборкой должны восстанавливаться автоматически.